# How to display custom validation messages in HTML5 style using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I created this Javascript function to validate the file extension before upload:

```
function validateFileExtension(field, extensions){
  file_extension = field.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if ($.inArray(file_extension,extensions) == -1){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
  /* Displays loading message after user submits a form */
  $("form.show-loading").submit(function(e){

    /* Validates spreadsheet extension */
    if ($(this).hasClass("file-upload")){
      field = $("input.spreadsheet");
      if (!validateFileExtension(field,['xls'])){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Invalid file extension. Allowed: .xls');
        return;
      }
    }

    //Displays loading spin
    $("div.panel-body").html(
      "<div class='loading'>"+
        "<img src='"+base_url+"/assets/images/loading.gif' class='loading'><p>Loading... Please wait</p>"+
      "</div>");
  });

});
```

It all works fine. I just want to display the error message in another way rather than an annoying alert.

Can I show it like those validation message bubbles that we see in HTML5 form elements?

E.g.: when an input has the 'required' property and the browser highlights that field showing a message bubble.

Comment: You can use toastr, I have linked the demo [here](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

Comment: @Rex Thanks. I'd rather something simpler tho. But I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example for Bootstrap.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validate').click(function() {
    $('#text').toggleClass('has-error');
    $('#text').parent().toggleClass('has-error');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input id="text" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter something here..." />
</div>
<input id="validate" type="button" value="Toggle" />
```

Comment: I tested it. It does add the 'has-error" class to my file input; I do have boostrap installed and working but it doesn't change the field appearance. And what about the error message?

Comment: Make sure you also have the "form-group" and " form-control". I didn't include an error message, but you can look that up here http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp I'm on the road now, so can't update my code.